# Adding npm packages to Laravel 5.4 project

Tags: npm, assets, laravel-5.4

How to add and configure npm packages to Laravel 5.4.* and make them work in right way?

Pre-history: 
I was looking a video of adding NOTY npm lib to Laravel 5.3, it uses `gulpfile.js`. So how to make it work in 5.4.

I think `npm install noty` is not enough.

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel 5.4, They change into Laravel Mix instead of elixir (see [Laravel Docs 5.4 - mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix)).

So, after When you fire "npm install [npm package]".
You must to use **webpack.mix.js** for handle all of your scss, less, js files in your projects.

```
//Example in webpack.mix.js

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

You can compile it in cmd via command.

```
> npm run dev //for development server
> npm run production  //for production server
```